# Add delete botton image from gallery js

Tags: javascript, image-gallery

I want to add X for delete an image from gallery users.
I search and see this code :[Link code](http://jsfiddle.net/kidino/DWv3k/)

He add Delete with span when user hover at image, i want same process but when i click "delete" or a icon do that form:

```
<form class='form-horizontal' role='form' method='post' action='/ServiceGallery.php'>
<button class='bot-ico' type='submit' value='" . $images['ID'] ."' name='imageid'><img src='/images/trash-ico.png'> </button>    <input type='HIDDEN' name='mill_act' value='gallery_action_delete' />
</form>";
```

can any help me ?